# Ios App for Ipad & Iphone different navigation bar items

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an app for iPad and iPhone, I've added multiple bar items to the navigation bar, but I want to add different bar items...
In the navigation bar from the iPad I just want to add 2 items to the right, which is already working. But I also want to add 2 other buttons to the left side of the iPhone navigation bar. But with the way that I'm trying it I get the same navigation bars, the same items, any ideas on how to add different items to the navigation bars.

Here's my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh 
  target:self action: @selector(IpadReload:)];

UIImage *emailIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emailicon.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *emailButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:(emailIcon) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(emailButtonTapped:)];

NSArray *rightButtonsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:refreshButton, emailButton, nil];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightButtonsArray;

UIBarButtonItem *previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target: self action: @selector(PreviousClicked:)];

UIImage *phoneIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"phoneicon.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *phoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:(phoneIcon) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(callPhone:)];

NSArray *leftButtonsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:previousButton, phoneButton, nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftButtonsArray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need to use iOS's built in enum of the current device and not isEqualToString:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad
} else {
    //  iPhone or iPod Touch - Add your two items to the right here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A succinct way to distinguish between iPhone and iPad would be:

```
BOOL iPad = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == 
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
// your setup
UIImage *buttonIcon = [UIImage imageNamed: 
   iPad ? @"padIcon.png" : @"phoneIcon.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First distinguish between iPhone and iPad  and add navigation bar items according to it
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

```
if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]){
//Add iPhone navigation items
}else if ([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]){
//Add iPad navigation items
}else{
```

//Default items for ipod etc
    }

Comment: It would be better to use the `userInterfaceIdiom` property to distinguish between iPhone and iPad.